# Math quote, who is this attributed to?

Tags: differential-topology

So there is a semi famous quote on 4 manifold theory, someone said 4 manifold theory is difficult because it is like the phase transition of matter. Anyone know who this quote is attributed to? I probably butchered it. If it sounds familiar or you know the reference, please reference.

Comment: Something like that is said here: http://www.cs.elte.hu/analysis/stipsicz/articles/s10.ps

Comment: As Qiaochu said, the quote is "One might think of dimension 4 as representing a phase transition between low- and high-dimensional topology, where we find uniquely complicated phenomena and diverse connections with other fields."  This is from the paper "4-Manifolds and Kirby calculus" by Gompf and Stipsicz.